# why does my $type variable get saved as 'Admin''?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, xampp

am trying to get the number of admins in my table it does work normally but now that i added inner join for two tables i get this error of an extra ' in the word admin and i don't know how to remove it
so here is my function in userc.php :

```
    function admincountsearch($key)
    {
        $con = config::getConnexion();
        $sql = "SELECT  user.username,user.name,user.lastname,user.id, 
                    user.email, user.image, user.verified, usero.type, 
                    usero.description,usero.ban 
            FROM user 
                INNER JOIN usero ON user.id_o = usero.id 
            WHERE user.username LIKE :keyword 
                OR user.id LIKE :keyword 
                OR user.name LIKE :keyword 
            WHERE usero.type=:type ";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $type ="Admin" ;
        $stmt->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $key . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':type',$type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $results = $stmt->rowCount();
        return $results;
    }
```

and here is how i call it in find.php:

```
<span class="info-box-number"><?php echo $userc->admincountsearch($key); ?></span>
```

and here is the error that i got:

> :  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE usero.type='Admin'' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Integre\Controller\userc.php:458
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Integre\Controller\userc.php(458): PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Integre\Views\find.php(200): userc->admincountsearch('g')
> #2 {main}
> thrown in

Comment: That's not an extra quote, it's matching the quote at the beginning of `'WHERE`, because you have 2 `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 `WHERE` clauses in your statement.
You probably meant

```sql
SELECT
  user.username,
  user.name,
  user.lastname,
  user.id,
  user.email,
  user.image,
  user.verified,
  usero.type,
  usero.description,
  usero.ban
FROM
    user
INNER JOIN usero ON
    user.id_o = usero.id
WHERE (
  user.username LIKE :keyword OR
  user.id LIKE :keyword OR
  user.name LIKE :keyword
) AND
usero.type=:type
```

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's, we make a simple comment and then close the question, as typos are almost never any use to others